# How do I delete all entities from my local Google App-engine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can I remove all entities or reset the local datastore on my dev_appserver? I accidentally recursively called a function to create an entity when testing.

I am using the Google App-engine SDK on Vista with Python.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore=yes myapp
```

See [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html) for more info.

Shorthand version:

```
dev_appserver.py -c
```

Comment: Wow, looked over that for sure. Thank you

Comment: If you are using the App Engine Launcher, you can do the same by putting the flags in "Extra Command Line Flags" field by going to Edit > Application Settings

Comment: this seems to be outdated or something... i get errors trying to use it

Comment: that didnt work but this did dev_appserver.py [app directory] --clear_datastore true

Comment: Any insight as to why this works, while deleting the entire "target" directory doesn't? Where exactly is the datastore being stored?

Answer (score 20):

If you came here for a **Java solution**: Delete the following file:

`{project root}/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin`

Rebuild and restart your project.

Comment: Can't find this directory in the project

Comment: I have found such file in `out/artifacts/xxxx_war_exploded/WEB-INF/appengine-generated`, the file seems surprisingly small, though - it is probably only some kind of index, real data (blobs?) are probably stored someplace else. I had to restart the server to complete the deletion.

Answer (score 4):

dev_appserver.py [app directory] --clear_datastore true

you need to shutdown the server if its running at the time to free the ports

Answer (score 2):

A useful thing to do is to always specify --datastore_path, e.g. --datastore_path=test.datastore.

To delete it you can then just delete the file. You can also keep copies and swap them in and out. And the store will persist over reboots (when /tmp/ the default location for it on Linux anyway, gets cleared)

Answer (score 0):

In production - you can go to
appengine dashboard => Datastore admin

Answer (score 0):

Here is my output after running dev_appserver

```
INFO     2017-03-21 15:07:36,085 devappserver2.py:764] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-03-21 15:07:38,342 api_server.py:268] Starting API server at: http://localhost:63970
INFO     2017-03-21 15:07:38,349 dispatcher.py:199] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2017-03-21 15:07:38,373 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at:
```

So I go to http://localhost:8000 and I am able to go to my local App Engine Admin Console and edit/delete datastore entities.

Answer (score -1):

in production, this may also come in handy (or be a security nightmare).

```
# will DELETE the database use http://localhost:8083/deletemodels?force=true
class DeleteModels(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

    def dMsg(msg):
      self.response.out.write(msg + '\n')
    n = self.request.get('force')
    if n:
      dMsg('clearing YourModelHere data....')
      for uc in YourModelHere.all():
               uc.delete()
               dMsg('.')
      dMsg('clearing YouNextModelHere data....')           
      for uc in YouNextModelHere.all():
               uc.delete()
               dMsg('.')
```

Comment: In production, you can also do it from the Datastore Admin, which submits a delete Task.