# How to empty Google App Engine's local database

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

Where do I go to delete everything in my local db?

I saw this: http://fourtyten.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-empty-google-app-engines-local.html

But my WEB-INF directory doesn't have a local_db.bin

I saw this post also [How to delete all datastore in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062540/how-to-delete-all-datastore-in-google-app-engine)

> If you're talking about the development datastore, you'll just have to delete the following file: "./WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin". The file will be generated for you again next time you run the development server and you'll have a clear db.

But I can't find this folder either.

--Update---
I found this post [How do I delete all entities from my local Google App-engine datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010573/how-do-i-delete-all-entities-from-my-local-google-app-engine-datastore) and it looks like I can use `dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore dennys`

But when I run that I get this `python dev_appserver.py --celar_datastore dennys
python: can't open file 'dev_appserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

How do I find where dev_appserver.py is on my machine?

Comment: Those are both for the Java version.

Comment: any idea how to do it for Python?

Comment: How do you normally launch dev_appserver? If you do it from an icon on your desktop, inspect the properties of that icon to find the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete data follow the steps here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#Using_the_Datastore

This question is not longer valid, my problem is listed here: [AppConfigNotFoundError for dev_appserver.py on Django-nonrel and Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824422/where-is-dev-appserver-py-for-django-nonrel-and-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 1):

Open up a terminal and execute the following

```
cd /
find . -iname "*dev_appserver.py*" -type f
```

then add that to your path in your .bash_profile as so

```
PATH=$PATH:<directory from previous command>
```

then use the dev_appserver.py as you had previously mentioned like so

```
dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore=yes <your app's directory>
```

Keep in mind that `python dev_appserver.py <your_app>` might not work