# AppConfigNotFoundError for dev_appserver.py on Django-nonrel and Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, django-nonrel

I'm trying to clear my local db like explained [in the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#Using_the_Datastore)

But when I try and run the `dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore` command I get `google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError`

```
dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore dennys
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 76, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 72, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 687, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 575, in main
    appinfo, matcher = dev_appserver.LoadAppConfig(root_path, {})
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 4359, in LoadAppConfig
    raise AppConfigNotFoundError
google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the directory of your application in the command line to dev_appserver.py.

Comment: as far as I can tell I am. I'm in the directory that holds my app, and I'm running: "dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore dennys" Where "dennys" is the name of my app

Comment: dev_appserver is looking for the path to your app, not just its name. I suspect you're running dev_appserver from the google_appengine directory; it's unlikely your project is in a subdirectory of that directory.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Moishe. I'm currently in my project directory: "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE
" and my project is in the directory "/Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/dennys
". So the path is the same as the project name. Should I be somewhere else to run the dev_appserver command?

Comment: Try: "/path-to-dev_appserver/dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore /Users/bryce/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/DennysBE/dennys"

Comment: The command ran fine, but when I started up the server using "python manage.py runserver" and go into the admin for the site, all the models are still there...

Comment: Maybe you can modify manage.py to pass the --clear_datastore command to dev_appserver.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by going to:

Run --> Debug Configurations --> (right click) PyDev Google App Run --> New

Type the project name under "Project".

**Then click on "Arguments" and put the path location of where your app.yaml file is.**  The picture below describes what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the boolean yes value as stated in the docs:

```
dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore=yes myapp
```