# app-engine ndb delete data

Tags: python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I'm new to app-engine [Python 2.7]
I would like to delete elements from my ndb (currently I don't care if it is one by one or all at once since none is working for me).

Version 1 based on [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948901/how-to-delete-ndb-entity-using-id):

```
ps_ancestors = req_query.fetch()
for ps_ancestor in ps_ancestors:
  self.response.write(ps_ancestor.key)
  ps_ancestor.key.delete()
```

It continues to print the same data without actually deleting anything

Version 2:
[myId currently have only the values 1,2,3]

```
ndb.Key(myId, 1).delete()
ndb.Key(myId, 2).delete()  
ndb.Key(myId, 3).delete()
```

The model:

```
class tmpReport (ndb.Model):
    myId = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    hisId = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010573/how-do-i-delete-all-entities-from-my-local-google-app-engine-datastore

solve my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not define your Entity key as an IntegerProperty.  Take a look at this documentation: [NDB Entities and Keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities)

In order to delete an entity from datastore you should first retrieve it by using a query or by its ID.  I recommend you to use a "keyname" when creating your entities (to use it as your custom ID):

```
   # Model declaration
   class tmpReport (ndb.Model):
       hisId = ndb.IntegerProperty()
       date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

# Store the entity
   report = tmpReport(id=1, hisId=5)
   report.put()
```

Then to retrieve and delete the previous entity use:

```
# Retrieve entity
report = ndb.Key("tmpReport", 1).get()
# Delete the entity
report.key.delete()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. delete() only exists on the key, so: `report.key.delete()` https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#deleting_entities

Comment: @Jonny is right: AttributeError: 'tmpReport' object has no attribute 'delete'

Answer (score 2):

```
k = users.query(users.name == 'abhinav')
for l in k.fetch(limit = 1):
    l.key.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query1 = tmpReport.query()
query2 = query1.filter(tmpReport.myId == int(myId)) 
#Add other filters as necessary 
query3 = query2.fetch()
query3[0].key.delete()
```

Removes the first entity(element) returned assuming myID is unique so there is only one element in the list.